# Play a sound from sdcard0 in android

Tags: android, audio

```
MediaPlayer mp;
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.test);
mp.start();
```

That's my code. It just plays a sound from **res/drawable/** folder. I need to play a sound from android's **sdcard0/Test Folder/testsound.amr** How to do this ?

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `setDataSource` Method:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
//set the source of the Sound...
mp.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/Test Folder/testsound.amr");
//load the file
mp.prepare(); 
//Do the thing (:
mp.start();
```

You can also do it dynamically by doing:

```
mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Test Folder/testsound.amr");
```

NOTE: I'm not clearly sure if you need to do `.getPath()` or not...